# Why does strtok cause a segfault in my program?

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault, token, strtok

I'm trying to build a function which takes in two strings of numbers like char `strArr[2] = {"1, 2, 3, 4, 5", "4, 5, 6, 7, 8"}` and parses them. While writing my function I got a seg fault, I've identified the exact line that seg faults it, and omitted everything after that line.

The offending line is a `strtok` call which takes in the first string and a delimiter to split at. Does anyone know what's going on?

Code in question:

```
void FindIntersection(char * strArr[]) { 

int nel1 = 1;
int nel2 = 1;
int i = 0;

/*Determine the number of elements in strArr[0] */
while(strArr[0][i] != '\0'){
    if(strArr[0][i] == ','){
        nel1++;
    }
    i++;
}

i = 0;
/* Determine the number of elements in strArr[1] */

while(strArr[1][i] != '\0'){
    if(strArr[1][i] == ','){
        nel2++;
    }
    i++;
}

int intArr1[nel1];
int intArr2[nel2];

/* parse the elements from each char array and place them in int arrays */

char delim[2] = ", ";   
char *token;
token = strtok(strArr[0], delim);
```

Comment: `char strArr[2] = {"1, 2, 3, 4, 5", "4, 5, 6, 7, 8"}` this is not how you store multiple strings in an array, provide a minimal reproducible version of code before the post is closed

Comment: `strtok` expects to get a string containing delimiters. You do not provide a valid C string as the nul-termination is missing: `char delim[2] = ", ";`

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
char strArr[2] = {"1, 2, 3, 4, 5", "4, 5, 6, 7, 8"};
```

If that is your *actual* code, that won't work - it creates a `char` array rather than an array of `char` *pointers.* Any decent compiler should complain about this.

---

And if what you have is actually `char *strArr ...` (an array of pointers), that won't work either. It is undefined behaviour to modify string literals, which is what `strtok` generally does to weave its magic.

---

In order to fix *that* problem (assuming that's what you've done), you can use the same trick as per the following snippet:

```cpp
char *x = "123";  // a pointer to string literal you should not modify.
char x[] = "123"; // a string array you can modify.
```

In other words, you can create a *multi-dimensional* array of characters rather than a one-dimensional array of character pointers to non-modifiable string literals.

The following gives you a modifiable set of strings using this method, though you need to watch out for the second dimension being large enough for all literals that will be used to initialise the arrays (enough for all characters *plus* one more for the `\0` string terminator):

```cpp
char strArr[][14] = {"1, 2, 3, 4, 5", "4, 5, 6, 7, 8"}
```

That also means that space may be wasted if you have, for example, one large string and many small strings - each will allocate the *maximum* size.

---

If you wanted to avoid having to specify the size of that second dimension and the wastage that may come with it, you can (as rici points out in a comment) use compound literals to initialise the `char` pointer array elements in such a way that they *are* writable:

```cpp
char *strArr[] = {
    (char[]){"1, 2, 3, 4, 5"},
    (char[]){"4, 5, 6, 7, 8"},
};
```

Comment: You're right, it's actually defined as:
  `char  *A[] = {"1, 3, 4, 7, 13", "1, 2, 4, 13, 15"};`
How do I turn them into normal character strings in order to start manipulating them?

Comment: @makeartandlove perhaps `char A[2][42] = {"1, 3, 4, 7, 13", "1, 2, 4, 13, 15"};`

Comment: To avoid counting characters: `char *strArr[] = {(char[]){"1, 2, 3, 4, 5"}, (char[]){"4, 5, 6, 7, 8"}};`

Comment: @rici, in C, the cast type must be scalar so an aggregate type (like an array) is not permitted. Even if that weren't an issue, you still have the same problem with string literals - casting does not create a *new* object, it simply reinterprets the object as something else. Hence the non-writability of the backing memory will probably still cause an issue.

Comment: @paxdiablo: it's not a cast; it's a compound literal. The semantics are the same as if there were a `static char <anonymous>[] = {"..."}` so it's not a string literal.

Comment: @rici, apologies, I didn't actually notice the braces around the literal, that does indeed turn it into a compound literal. Will add that to the answer...